# Rack bags options

Tags: compatibility, rack, bags

I've attached a rack to my bike, [this one](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/tilt-folding-bike-rear-pannier-rack-20-id_8328464.html):

[image: rack]

Now my question is: what are my options for bags or something I can attach to it?
I'm not asking about a product rec, just for a list of options with pros and cons for each.

The rack was bought primary to mount a child seat on it, so if there are options to carry both a seat and a bag it would be great.

Comment: Have the child hold the bag?

Comment: @Swifty I dont think he can carry a reasonable bag. Even if he could - there is no way to convince him not to throw it away. He's 1.5 years old)

Comment: Ah, he’s a bit of a weight weenie, would ditch the bag to go faster, smart kid.

Comment: Could you add a picture of the rack, with seat attached, fitted to your own bike? I've done a couple of things like this myself, but I'm not sure if they'd be suitable.  Also you *may* have room to wear a backpack - I tended not to until I could ask my daughter if it was OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a specific recommendation from the manufacturer about a way to have both bags and a child seat, I would not recommend it. Most of universal rack panniers have some sorts of straps going over rack's rails which would interfere with the child seat.

Consider another option: move the load forward, i.e. install a front rack to carry bags. This way the bike would be even more balanced when carrying the weight.

Comment: Another option is to use the style of child's seat that sits over the top tube.  That's better balance than having the kid out the back.